# как контролировать checkbox-ы

Tags: reactjs, redux

я конечно получаю по итогу массив имен кликнутых чекбохов но никак не магу понят как их
контролировать по принципу кликнул -> диспатч -> перерисовка с кликнутым чекбохом

```
//компонент
export const Icons = () => {
const dispatch = useDispatch()
const checkedArray = useSelector(state => state.iconForm)
console.log(checkedArray);
const changeHandler = (e) => {
    if(!e.target.checked){
        dispatch({type:UNCHECK,payload:e.target.name})
        return
    }
    dispatch({type:CHECK,payload:e.target.name})
}

const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
}
return (
    <div className={styles.iconsForm}>
        <form>
            <label className="label" onChange={changeHandler}>
                <input name="111" type="checkbox"/>
            </label>
            <label className="label" onChange={changeHandler}>
                <input name="222" type="checkbox"/>
            </label>
            <label className="label" onChange={changeHandler}>
                <input name="333" type="checkbox"/>
            </label>
            <button onClick={submitHandler}>abcd</button>
        </form>
    </div>
)
}



//редюсер
const initialState = {
activeIcons:[],
}
export const iconFormReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
switch(action.type){
    case CHECK:
        return {
            ...state,
            activeIcons:[...state.activeIcons,action.payload]
        }
    case UNCHECK:
        return {
            ...state,
            activeIcons:state.activeIcons.filter(e => e != action.payload)
        }
    default:
        return state
}
}

export const CHECK = 'APP/CHECK'
export const UNCHECK = 'APP/UNCHECK'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не надо результат сохранять в redux при каждом изменении checkbox-ов.

Храните в локальном стейте и при отправке формы добавьте их в redux и отправляйте куда надо.

Во вторых `onChange` желательно повесить на сам `checkbox`, а не на `label`.

```
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    first: false,
    second: false,
    third: false
  });

  const handleCheckbox = (e) => {
    const { name, checked } = e.target;
    setState((prev) => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        [name]: checked
      };
    });
  };
  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("тут надо добавлять в redux", state);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form>
        <label className="label">
          <input
            name="first"
            onChange={handleCheckbox}
            checked={state.first || ""}
            type="checkbox"
          />
        </label>
        <label className="label">
          <input
            name="second"
            onChange={handleCheckbox}
            checked={state.second || ""}
            type="checkbox"
          />
        </label>
        <label className="label">
          <input
            name="third"
            onChange={handleCheckbox}
            checked={state.third || ""}
            type="checkbox"
          />
        </label>
        <button onClick={submitHandler}>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[**Codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-elion-l9xuc?file=/src/App.js:58-1261)

Comment: спасибо!  2.не в label есть еше и картинка я просто упростил, 1.я думал есть какой то хитрый способ а надо было просто описать каждый

Comment: @Armen если ответ решил вашу проблему примите его нажав на галочку рядом с ним.

Comment: да решил но можно подождать 1-2 дня может кто то подкинет алтернативу... мне интерестно всетаки может есть еше какой то способ